# What is the entry upstream in hgrc for?

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

In the *hgrc* file for my repository, I have two paths, one `default` and the other `upstream`. They are identical.

Do I need the entry for `upstream` and if so why? I have no idea why I have that for `upstream`.

```
[paths]
default = https://myUrl
upstream = https://myUrl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just another saved remote repository.

You can name these anything you want, the "default" name is useful in that you don't have to mention where to push to or pull from, but you can name these remote repositories, "upstream" is just such a name.

If the url of "upstream" is the same as for "default" then most likely you don't need it, unless you have scripts or programs that rely on being able to issue `hg pull upstream` or similar.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure we do not use "upstream" anywhere, so for simplicity we will remove it. It probably crept in when we started up, perhaps by copying the hgrc file from another project.

Comment: "default" and "default-push" are both used by commands. Are there any others?